# Implementation of a list on a pointers

Tags: c++, list

Let's make a list

```
struct node
{
    node *next=nullptr;
    int value=0;
};
```

1. Why do we start a list with a pointer `node *head=nullptr`, but not with an object `node head`? Is such an implementation faster than creating each node as an object whose fields are a value and a pointer to the next object? I don't understand how this implementation works.

I added function that adds new node to the front

```
void addFront(node *&head, int value)
{
    node *nodeToAdd=new node;
    nodeToAdd->value=value;
    nodeToAdd->next=head;
    head=nodeToAdd;
}
```

and another one that shows the list.

```
    addFront(head1, 2);
    showList(head1);
    node *head2=new node;
    addFront(head2, 2);
    showList(head2);
```

2. Why first showList display `2` and the second one `2 0`? The only difference is in `head1` and `head2` declaration.

Comment: `Why do we start a list with a pointer node *head=nullptr, but not with an object node head?` Because a `node` can't contain a `node`. Its infinite recursion.

Comment: So why pointers can do this?

Comment: The difference between having a node in a node and a pointer to a node in a node is building a copy of your house in your house and having a note with your houses address laying in your house.

Comment: *"Why do we start a list with a pointer `node *head=nullptr`, but not with an object `node head`?"* -- Depends on who "we" consists of, I guess. Some people do start their linked lists with a [sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), not a pointer. It's tough to answer a question based on a false premise; would you find it acceptable for someone to post an answer consisting of a refutation of your false premise?

Comment: Please stick to only one question per question. Also, for your second question, you should probably include a [mre], something with *just enough* code for someone to copy the code, compile it, and reproduce your result. It's good that you are sticking to minimal code, but you may have taken minimalism a bit too far.